# How to remove child element click event?

Tags: javascript, events

Need your help on this one. In navigation bar i have an item called author which shows info about author when clicked, in a form of dropdown. The problem is that dropdown is clickable and that makes it disappear. I want to be able to show/close it only in navigation bar.

```
<div id = 'Author' class = 'navbarItem'>Author
   <div id = 'authorInfo'>
         // info about author
   </div>
```

```
const author = document.getElementById('Author');
const authorInfo = document.getElementById('authorInfo');

author.onclick = () => {
     if(authorInfo.style.display == 'none' || authorInfo.style.display == '')
          authorInfo.style.display = 'block'
     else 
          authorInfo.style.display = 'none';     
}
```

Have tried setting onclick event of authorInfo to null, that doesn't work.

Comment: You can use event.stopPropagation() technique in this scenario.

Comment: Have tried that as well but no expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the event parameter on listener to test if click was made on containter and not on its child. `event.target` holds the clicked element.

```js
const author = document.getElementById('Author');
const authorInfo = document.getElementById('authorInfo');

// You need the event parameter on function
author.onclick = function(event) {
     // Do it only if clicked element is author div, not its child
     if(event.target == author) {
         if(authorInfo.style.display == 'none' || authorInfo.style.display == '')
             authorInfo.style.display = 'block'
         else 
             authorInfo.style.display = 'none';     
     }
}
```

```html
<div id = 'Author' class = 'navbarItem'>Author
   <div id = 'authorInfo' style="display:none;">
         // info about author
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it, appreciate your help.